# how to read an external file when swift is sandboxed

Tags: swift, sandbox

I'm learning to program in Swift. My first program is running with a small amount of test data. It's working as designed, and now I'm ready to start using some live data. To do that, I copied a data file into the documents directory, but I can't read it. The error says file does not exist. I think my problem is a result of sandboxing. I tried to move that data file to the Swift's sandbox directory, but I can't find that directory.  I have no problem writing a file to the sandbox, and reading it back, but only inside the sandbox. I'm working in MyPlayground.

I just need to read an external file once to convert it to the format I need for my program. It's a static file, so  I only need to do it once.

What do I need to do, will this help?

```
path.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

I get my path using NSSearch

```
func readFromDocumentsFile(fileName:String) -> String {
   let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
   let path = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
   letcheckValidation = FileManager.default
   varfile:String

   ifcheckValidation.fileExists(atPath: path) {
       do{
           print("The file is there")
      try file = NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String
       }catch{
           file = "Error reading file"
       }
       } else{
       file = "\(fileName) is not there"
   }
   returnfile
}
```

Comment: `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` has no effect unless you created a Security Scoped Bookmark. And you don't need it to have access to the application container. Drop the `NS...` stuff, there are native Swift APIs. Playgrounds work differently, they have special containers. Test your code in a project.

Comment: Well that rules out Security Scoped Resource. I would expect that I can turn 'sandboxing' off in a project. I did try to turn 'sandboxing' off, but could not find it. Perhaps my second program can be a new project that simply reads the input file and writes a new one, but I would face the same challenge of getting the file I create into the Swift sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I can create more than one Playground, so I created a new one that does nothing more than read an write a file. When I created the Playground it asked if this was for IOS or MACOS. Selecting IOS resulted in my test application running sandboxed. This time I selected MACOS, and I was then able to write to the documents folder, and see my file there.

My solution for getting test data into the sandbox was to go back to the original data on the PC, load it into EXCEL and use EXCEL functions to remove excess data. That way I could narrow down 170k lines of data to 6.5k lines. Then I copy and pasted those lines into my code as line001 and line002 using multiple line variables.

```
    let line001 = """
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqr
stuvwx
    (3000 lines of data)
    """
    let line002 = """
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopwr
stuvwx
    (3500 lines of data
    """
```

Then I wrote the test data out to a new file in the sandbox where I can use as an input file to my application running in the IOS Playground.

```
let WriteString = line001 + "\n" + line002
writeToDocumentsFile(fileName:fileName,value:WriteString)
```

Perhaps I could have done it all with one variable line001, but I did not know how many lines could be defined.